# How to get handle of an awaitable Task?

Tags: c#

I am a newbie in Tasks and still learning this topic so be gentle with me (I think I have some fundamental mess-ups with my below code...)

Please look at the below exercise which will help me describe my question:
I have a simple "MyService" class which has a "Do_CPU_Intensive_Job" method called by the "Run" method. My purpose is to be able to run several instances of the "Do_CPU_Intensive_Job" method (which itself run on a different thread than the UI as its CPU bound), sometimes synchronously and sometimes asynchronously.

In other words, assuming I have 2 instances of MyService, sometimes I want these 2 methods running together and sometimes not.

```
class MyService
{
    private bool async;
    private string name;
    private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
    private CancellationToken token;
    private bool isRunning = false;
    private Task myTask = null;

    public MyService(string name, bool async)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.async = async;
    }

    public string Name { get { return name; } }
    public bool IsRunning { get { return isRunning; } }

    public async Task Run ()
    {
        isRunning = true;
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        token = tokenSource.Token;

        if (async)
            myTask = Do_CPU_Intensive_Job();
        else
            await Do_CPU_Intensive_Job();     // I cannot do myTask = await Do_CPU_Intensive_Job(); so how can the "Stop" method wait for it??
    }

    public async Task Stop ()
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();

        if (myTask != null)
            await myTask;

        isRunning = false;
    }

    private async Task Do_CPU_Intensive_Job ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("doing some heavy job for Task " + name);
        int i = 0;
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task: " + name + " - " + i);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            i++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Task " + name + " not yet completed! I need to do some cleanups");

        await Task.Delay(2000); //simulating cleanups
        Console.WriteLine("Task " + name + " - CPU intensive and cleanups done!");
    }
}
```

So, I have the below GUI which which works well but only if the 2 instances are running asynchronously. "works well" means that when stopping the tasks, it stops nicely by running entire "Do_CPU_Intensive_Job" method. hence the last message will be from the GUI ("Both tasks are completed...now doing some other stuff"). So far so good.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<MyService> list = null;
    MyService ms1 = null;
    MyService ms2 = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list = new List<MyService>();
        ms1 = new MyService("task 1", true);
        ms2 = new MyService("task 2", true);
        list.Add(ms1);
        list.Add(ms2);
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (MyService item in list)
            await item.Run();
    }

    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (MyService item in list)
        {
            if (item.IsRunning)
            {
                await item.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Done stopping Task: " + item.Name);
            }
        }

        //now ready to do some other stuff
        Console.WriteLine("Both tasks are completed...now doing some other stuff");
    }
}
```

Problem starts when the 2 instances are not running simultaneously. In that case, I get the "Both tasks are completed...now doing some other stuff" from the GUI **before** "Do_CPU_Intensive_Job" is really completed...

```
        ms1 = new MyService("task 1", false);
        ms2 = new MyService("task 2", false);
```

this is not happening when both tasks are running together because I have the handle (myTask) when running asynchronously which I dont when running synchronously.

```
await Do_CPU_Intensive_Job(); // I cannot do myTask = await Do_CPU_Intensive_Job(); so how can the "Stop" method wait for it??
```

Thanks, all

Comment: `Do_CPU_Intensive_Job().Wait()`?

Comment: @MeirionHughes Thanks for replying. Do you mean instead of await, use .Wait()?

Comment: I don't completely understand your problem, but yes, calling `.Wait()` is definitely something I did a lot before `async/await` existed.

Comment: @MeirionHughes Sorry but it doesn't work....

Comment: @JonathanAllen Thanks for replying. My problem is that when stopping, I get back to the GUI *before* the "Do_CPU_Intensive_Job" completes. Happens when awaiting the "Do_CPU_Intensive_Job" method. (ms1 = new MyService ("task 1", false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time hammering out the code to a point that I think it is doing what is expected.

The first problem I found is that you can't just pass the cancellation token into your method, you need to relate it to the task(s) that are to be cancelled. Unfortunately I could not find a way to do this directly on an `async` method but have a look at the `MyService` class here for how I was able to do this.

```
class MyService
{
    private bool async;
    private string name;
    private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
    private bool isRunning = false;
    private Task myTask = null;

    public MyService(string name, bool async)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.async = async;
    }

    public string Name { get { return name; } }
    public bool IsRunning { get { return isRunning; } }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        isRunning = true;
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        myTask = Task.Run(() => Do_CPU_Intensive_Job(tokenSource.Token), tokenSource.Token);
        if (!async)
            await myTask;
    }

    public async Task Stop()
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();

        if (myTask != null)
            await myTask;

        isRunning = false;
    }

    private void Do_CPU_Intensive_Job(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("doing some heavy job for Task " + name);
        int i = 0;
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task: " + name + " - " + i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            i++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Task " + name + " not yet completed! I need to do some cleanups");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Task " + name + " - CPU intensive and cleanups done!");
    }
}
```

The Run method is now using `Task.Run` to call `Do_CPU_Intensive_Job` and if you note I am passing the token to both the work method and to the `Task.Run` call. The latter is what links the token to that Task/Thread and the former is what allows us to watch for the cancellation request.

The final piece is how we call Run on the service instances, by calling `await` on a Task or async method the thread is being released but the remainder of the code in the method is extracted and will not be run until the awaited task completes.

I was just using a unit test in order to work on the code rather than a button but the premise should be the same, but here is how I was able to run the tasks in synchronous mode and still be able to call stop on them.

```
var service1 = new MyService("task 1", false);
var service2 = new MyService("task 2", false);

service1.Run(); //Execution immediately moves to next line
service2.Run(); // Same here

await service1.Stop(); //Execution will halt here until task one has fully stopped so task 2 actually continues running
await service2.Stop();
```

Comment: Thanks, but when adding the Wait(token), the Do_CPU_Intensive_Job gets stuck and do only 1 iteration...

Comment: @RichardDeer I think that may be down to an oversight on my part, I've edited my answer to resolve that oversight. Give the updated version a shot.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I have modified the code as you suggested but still I get only the 1st iteration in the Do_CPU_intensive_Job. I have fixed this by adding: .ConfigureAwait(false) to the Task.Delay(1000) and now its running but the GUI is frozen!, so I cannot press the Stop button to test it...

Comment: @RichardDeer I think I was able to get your code running as you were expecting, i've completely re written my answer to show the changes I made and hopefully explain why. If anything is not clear, or if I'm completely off base about your expectations let me know :)

Comment: Thanks, Phaeze for your support! It is working now. I will digest the changes you made! Cheers!